# 31 as sum of 4 different numbers from 1 to 18

Tags: combinations

No.of ways of selecting 4  different numbers from the set A={1,2,3,4,..,18} whose sum is 31.

I know combinations with multinomial theorem but here we want distinct no.s.
How to eliminate the ways of getting 2 or 3 no.s repeated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not tag a language,

I would do something like this in php,

```
 $set = [];
$combinations = [[]];
$length = 4;
$sum_value = 18; 
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    $set[] = range(1, $sum_value);
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $tmp = [];
    foreach ($combinations as $v1) {
        foreach ($set[$i] as $v2)
            $tmp[] = array_merge($v1, [$v2]);
    }
    $combinations = $tmp;
}
$result=[];
foreach ($combinations as $c) {
    if(count($c) == count(array_unique($c)))
        if(array_sum($c) == $sum_value)
        {
            $result[]=$c;
        }
}
echo 'Total '.count($result).' combinations of length '.$length.' for sum = '. $sum_value; 
//print_r($result);
```